# Remote Login via Finder: Choose user account without entering password

Tags: macos, finder, login

I'm using a Mac mini as an HTPC with two user accounts: one standard account and one admin account to manage the Mac. I'd like to have screensharing access to both, so I enabled it (and also File Sharing) for both accounts.

When I select the Mini in the Finder sidebar, it prompts me for the login credentials. I don't want to enter them each time though. I checked the box to save the credentials in the Key Chain and did the same for the other account. I can see both items in the Key Chain, but when I connect to the Mini again, it always logs me in with the credentials I saved first.

Is there a way to configure it to allow me to simply choose one of the accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplish this in Safari:

```
vnc://username:password@server
```

If I then create a bookmark, whenever I execute it, it will open up without prompting me for the password. For the sake of convenience, I save the bookmark to the desktop.

EDIT: Additionally, you can copy the bookmark to a location (such as the desktop), and change the file extension to .vncloc to open Screen Sharing directly.